# Incremental Building in VS 2005?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2005

We have a 50 projects solution in VS 2005.

Is any way to get incremental build if nothing was changed?

It is kind of doing it now, but it executes all prebuild and post build events for each project.

The compiling itself is not happenning, but it iterates through all projects and executes all prebuild and post build events for each project.

Is any way to prevent it?

Comment: This is a **duplicate** question: > [Build Incrementally in VS 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227991/build-incrementally-in-vs-2005)

Comment: Exact duplicate (by the same user) of [Build Incrementally in VS 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227991/build-incrementally-in-vs-2005)

Answer (score 1):

[See my answer in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227991/build-incrementally-in-vs-2005#231867).

Comment: Why would you post a duplicate answer, but not bother to vote to close the question?

Comment: @Justin, *three years later* you're asking this?

Comment: Huh, yeah this question really *is* old!  (Another answer on this question was flagged)

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a separate project config, like Debug_INC, and no pre or post build events in those configs, then just run them when needed.